# Trigger refresh after POST request (either AJAX or XMLHttpRequest)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to get the exact same behavior of a submission from an HTML Form with `method="POST"`, but without using a form, and it seems to be impossible but I don't understand why (if it is because security concerns, or something).

The exact situation is the following: I want to send a JSON through POST, and at the end trigger a refresh with the answer of this request, but

1. The html Form does not accept JSON as an encoding for the fields (I found some draft of a specification where it said using `enctype=application/json` in the form was going to be eventually supported, but seems to be dead already)
2. XMLHttpRequest and Ajax both send the data through POST successfully, but neither of those trigger a refresh with the response's content at the end of the asynchronous background call. I can Draw the contents in some div in my page, but as my POST request is sent to another domain, this has quite an undesired effect of displaying another website's content in my site.

More or less, my attempt with XMLHttpRequest is the following:

```
let my_values = {
    field1: 10
}
let my_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
// POST to another domain
my_request.open("POST", "http://another.domain.com/");
function refresh(){
    // Here I would like to somehow trigger a refresh with
    // my_request.responseText's content, and the browser having
    // another.domain.com as URL, so, a redirect more or less.
}
my_request.onload = refresh;
my_request.send(JSON.stringify(my_values));
```

The closest I have been is what is described in [this](https://systemoverlord.com/2016/08/24/posting-json-with-an-html-form.html) website, doing a trick like this:

```html
<form method='POST' enctype='text/plain'>
  <input name='{"field1": 10, "trash": "' value='"}'>
</form>
```

but it kinda seems like I expose myself to some sort of an SQL-Injection-like attack, and even if it is not the case, I would prefer not to clutter the json with some unnecessary field just to be able to send the JSON from a form.

Why is it that I cannot treat the execution of an XMLHttpRequest as a click on an `href`? Would it expose some vulnerability? Thanks a lot in advance, and sorry if the question is repeated/senseless.

Comment: You will improve the chances of getting any help and the quality of help gotten by providing the source codes.

Comment: I will add some small code examples, thank you.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp.